# Why can't I add minted environment to a variable using \gappto?

Tags: minted, etoolbox

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\newminted[mycode]{text}{}
\newcommand\foo{}
\gappto\foo{
  \begin{mycode}
  Hello, world!
  \end{mycode}
}
\foo
\end{document}
```

It doesn't compile. Why so?

Comment: like all verbatim commands minted constructs can not be used in the argument of another command (that is why minted has its own newminted declaration rather than simply being able to use newenvironment)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle is there a workaround by any chance or that's it?

Comment: no real workaround you can never use these things nested (you can always work around one level) as the outer command has already tokenised the input so newlines are already spaces any tex special characters are tokenised with their tex meanings etc, so by the time minted starts it is too late to recover.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle got it :( please, post an answer and we call it a day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like all verbatim commands minted constructs can not be used in the argument of another command (that is why minted has its own `\newminted` declaration rather than simply being able to use `\newenvironment`)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but with code-as-text, formatting could be applied, on the one hand; and on the other, controlled expansion of code could be useful. A sort of listing-emulator, in other words. (Spaces aren't converted via regex in this example, but can be.)

[image: listing]

But gets mind-bending very quickly (in a Klein-bottle way).

For usability, the trick would seem to be having *both* verbatim-like text and runnable code, in parallel, instead of just one or the other.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%=====
\tl_new:N \l_mytemp_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mytempa_tl
\tl_new:N \g_mytempr_tl
%=====
\newcommand\docmdscan{
%park these
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\c{par}) } %\par
                {   } %markup
                \l_mytemp_tl    
                
%replace these
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\c{[A-Za-z]*}) } %any control sequence with Latin letters
                { \c{token_to_str:N} \1  } %convert to string
                \l_mytemp_tl    
    
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cB.) } %match on opening group
                { \1\c{\{}  } %insert a text brace
                \l_mytemp_tl
    
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
            { (\cE.) } %match on closing group
            { \1\c{\}}  } %insert a text brace
             \l_mytemp_tl

    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cP.) } %match on macro parameter token
                { \c{\#}  } %replace with text hash
                \l_mytemp_tl
%               \tl_show:N              \l_mytemp_tl

%  \regex_match:nnTF { [\cM.]+ } { \l_mytemp_tl } { dollar } { }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cM.) } %match on maths shift (inline=$, display=\[ and \]
                { \c{\$}  } %replace with text dollar
                \l_mytemp_tl

    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cU.) } %supercript=up
                { \c{textasciicircum} } %
                \l_mytemp_tl    
                
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cD.) } %subscript=down
                { \c{\_} } %
                \l_mytemp_tl    

% re-insert \par
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                {   } %markup
                { \c{par} } %\par
                \l_mytemp_tl    


}

\NewDocumentCommand { \scanbraces } { m } {

    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % no expansion
    \docmdscan
    \tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cdr } { +m } {

    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % no expansion
    \docmdscan
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour
    \tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl} ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ #1
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mytempr_tl { #1 }
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cdrb } { +m } {

    \tl_gclear:N \l_mytemp_tl 
    \tl_set:No \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % one expansion
    \docmdscan
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour
    \tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl} ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ #1
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mytempr_tl { #1 }
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cdrc } { +m } {

    \tl_gclear:N \l_mytempa_tl 
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytempa_tl { #1 } % no expansion
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour
        \tl_to_str:N \l_mytempa_tl} ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ 
%       \tl_show:N \l_mytempa_tl
        
    \tl_gclear:N \l_mytemp_tl 
    \tl_set:No \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % one expansion
    \docmdscan
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour
    \tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl} ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ #1
    ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ \cddumpb
%   \tl_gset:Nn \g_mytempr_tl { #1 }
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cd } { +m } {

    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % no expansion
    \docmdscan
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour\tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl}
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mytempr_tl { #1 }
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cddump } { } {
%inline:
    $\langle$ \cddumpb $\rangle$
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \cddumpb } { } {
    \tl_use:N \g_mytempr_tl 
}



\NewDocumentEnvironment { cdenv } { +b } {
    \cd { #1 }
} { }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { mycode } { +b } {
    \begin{cdenv}
    #1 
    \end{cdenv}
} { }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { cdenvb } { +b } {
    \cdrb { #1 }
} { }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { mycodeb } { +b } {
    \begin{cdenvb}
    #1 
    \end{cdenvb}
} { }


\newcommand\cdcodefont{\ttfamily}
\newcommand\cdcodefontcolour{\color{blue}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcommand\foo{}
\gappto\foo{
  \begin{mycode}
  Hello, \textbf{world}! $x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}$
  \end{mycode}
}
\foo

\foo

\foo

The code has been repeated three times, and the output is \cddump.

\bigskip
%(A) \cdr{\foo}
%
%(B) \cdrb{\foo}

(C) \cdrc{\foo}
\end{document}
```

With pars:

[image: paragraphs]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%=====
\tl_new:N \l_mytemp_tl
\tl_new:N \l_mytempa_tl
\tl_new:N \g_mytempr_tl
%=====
\newcommand\docmdscan{
%park these
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\c{par}) } %\par
                {   } %markup
                \l_mytemp_tl    
                
%replace these
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\c{[A-Za-z]*}) } %any control sequence with Latin letters
                { \c{token_to_str:N} \1  } %convert to string
                \l_mytemp_tl    
    
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cB.) } %match on opening group
                { \1\c{\{}  } %insert a text brace
                \l_mytemp_tl
    
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
            { (\cE.) } %match on closing group
            { \1\c{\}}  } %insert a text brace
             \l_mytemp_tl

    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cP.) } %match on macro parameter token
                { \c{\#}  } %replace with text hash
                \l_mytemp_tl
%               \tl_show:N              \l_mytemp_tl

%  \regex_match:nnTF { [\cM.]+ } { \l_mytemp_tl } { dollar } { }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cM.) } %match on maths shift (inline=$, display=\[ and \]
                { \c{\$}  } %replace with text dollar
                \l_mytemp_tl

    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cU.) } %supercript=up
                { \c{textasciicircum} } %
                \l_mytemp_tl    
                
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                { (\cD.) } %subscript=down
                { \c{\_} } %
                \l_mytemp_tl    

% re-insert \par
    \regex_replace_all:nnN 
                {   } %markup
                { \c{par} } %\par
                \l_mytemp_tl    


}

\NewDocumentCommand { \scanbraces } { m } {

    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % no expansion
    \docmdscan
    \tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cdr } { +m } {

    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % no expansion
    \docmdscan
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour
    \tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl} ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ #1
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mytempr_tl { #1 }
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cdrb } { +m } {

    \tl_gclear:N \l_mytemp_tl 
    \tl_set:No \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % one expansion
    \docmdscan
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour
    \tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl} ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ #1
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mytempr_tl { #1 }
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cdrc } { +m } {

    \tl_gclear:N \l_mytempa_tl 
    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytempa_tl { #1 } % no expansion
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour
        \tl_to_str:N \l_mytempa_tl} ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ 
%       \tl_show:N \l_mytempa_tl
        
    \tl_gclear:N \l_mytemp_tl 
    \tl_set:No \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % one expansion
    \docmdscan
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour
    \tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl} ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ #1
    ~~ $\mapsto$ ~ \cddumpb
%   \tl_gset:Nn \g_mytempr_tl { #1 }
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cd } { +m } {

    \tl_set:Nn \l_mytemp_tl { #1 } % no expansion
    \docmdscan
    {\cdcodefont\cdcodefontcolour\tl_use:N \l_mytemp_tl}
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_mytempr_tl { #1 }
    
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \cddump } { } {
%inline:
    $\langle$ \cddumpb $\rangle$
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \cddumpb } { } {
    \tl_use:N \g_mytempr_tl 
}



\NewDocumentEnvironment { cdenv } { +b } {
    \cd { #1 }
} { }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { mycode } { +b } {
    \begin{cdenv}
    #1 
    \end{cdenv}
} { }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { cdenvb } { +b } {
    \cdrb { #1 }
} { }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { mycodeb } { +b } {
    \begin{cdenvb}
    #1 
    \end{cdenvb}
} { }


\newcommand\cdcodefont{\ttfamily}
\newcommand\cdcodefontcolour{\color{blue}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcommand\foo{}
\gappto\foo{
  \begin{mycode}
  
  
  Hello, \textbf{world}! 
  
  $x^{2}+y^{2}=z^{2}$
  
  \end{mycode}
}
\foo

\foo

\foo

The code has been repeated three times, and the output is \cddump.

\bigskip
%(A) \cdr{\foo}
%
%(B) \cdrb{\foo}

(C) \cdrc{\foo}
\end{document}
```